# How to hide specific post on the homepage but should be visible only if the category is filtered from the filter bar present on the homepage

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a WordPress website. I have 5-6 categories on my website. One of them is Expired deals which I don't want to visible on the homepage but at the same time, if someone clicks that category from a filter bar then, only posts pertaining to that category should be visible.

URL - https://saashunter.com/

I want to hide posts of Expired Deals from the homepage once they are really expired but rather than deleting them, I want to hide and they should be visible only if the category is filtered from the filter bar present above the posts on the homepage.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: Please don't post URLs to a site. The site will change over time, making this question redundant and useless for future users with similar issues. Post the relevant code directly in the question in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

1. Via Dashboard->Posts->Categories hover over "Expired deals" to identify its tag_ID e.g. 17
2. create (changing 17 to the  category ID you identified above), upload and activate the following plugin (or add code to your existing site functions plugin)

   ```
   <?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: Theme independent functions
   Description: Not tested
   Version: 1.0
   */
   function exclude_category( $query ) {
       if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
           $query->set( 'cat', '-17' );
       }
   }
   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
   ?>
   ```
3. Any category selection widget should still work and still display posts for the excluded category. You've not identified menubar filter code but you could hard code the link for Expired Deal categories e.g. `<a href="/?cat=17">etc` and WP URL rewrite as necessary.

Bonus:

Code to exclude individually specified posts where custom field 'no_recent_post_list' has been set for a post with an entry of e.g. "TRUE".

```
function my_exclude_post($query) {
   if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
        $myargs = array(
            array(
              'key' => 'no_recent_post_list',
              'value'=>false, // ONLY REQD PRE 3.9
              'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
         );
         $query->set( 'meta_query', $myargs);
   }
 }
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_exclude_post');
```

Credit for first example code above: Wordpress Codex but I've lost the link lol.